# Adding sub query - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following SQL query but this is not quite what I want:

```
SELECT 
    TOP (20) Attribs.ImageID AS ItemID 
FROM 
    Attribs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Items ON Attribs.ImageID = Items.ImageID 
WHERE
    (attribID IN ('a','b','c','d','e')) 
    AND (deleted NOT IN (1,2)) 
    AND Attribs.attribID = 'a' AND Attribs.attribID = 'b'
GROUP BY 
    Attribs.ImageID 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(DISTINCT attribID) DESC
```

What I need is to query

```
   AND Attribs.attribID = 'a' AND Attribs.attribID = 'b'
```

first, then rest of the WHERE clause based on the above query results.

Is this possible to achieve using sub query?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Thank you

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, I don't think this makes any difference which condition takes priority.

Comment: Your search terms are contradictory.  No record will have a value for attribID which is both "a", "b", or "c" and also either "123" or "456" (let alone both!).  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Joh, You are right. I updated sample Query. What I want is (in this case) to get results of 'a' and 'b' then get imageID which has the most matching attribID in (a,b,c,d,e). Lets say I have itemID 1-a,c,d itemID 2-a,b,c, itemID 3-a,b. In this case itemID 1 will not be included in the results although it has the most matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally getting the reason why you want to do this one query *first* before the other.... but you could use a Common Table Expression (CTE) - something like this:

```
;WITH FirstQuery AS
(
    SELECT a.ImageId
    FROM dbo.Attribs a
    WHERE a.attribID = 'a' AND a.attribID = 'b'
)
SELECT 
    TOP (20) a.ImageID AS ItemID 
FROM 
    dbo.Attribs a
INNER JOIN
    FirstQuery fq ON a.ImageId = fq.ImageId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Items i ON a.ImageID = i.ImageID 
WHERE
    (attribID IN ('a','b','c','d','e')) 
    AND (deleted NOT IN (1,2)) 
GROUP BY 
    a.ImageID 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(DISTINCT attribID) DESC
```

With this, you *first* select the `ImageID` from your `dbo.Attribs` table in the CTE, and then join that result set with the result of the table and join to the `Items` table.

Comment: I would like to query because WHERE a.attribID = 'a' AND a.attribID = 'b' is the attribID that ImageID has to have.  (attribID IN ('a','b','c','d','e')) is the condition doesn't apply to all because it counts how many of them applies to the ImageID

Comment: Also I realized that WHERE a.attribID = 'a' AND a.attribID = 'b' doesn't work. It should be SELECT ImageID, count(attribs.attribID) OVER (partition BY imageID) AS Numattribs FROM attribs WHERE attribs.attribID IN ('a','b')) a LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON a.ImageID = Items.ImageID WHERE numattribs = 2  .Sorry I should've caught that before I post the question.

Comment: It looks like replacing my query in previous post with your query inside "WITH FirstQuery AS" is what I need. Could you tell me why everyone is wondering why I want to query first before the other? Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do that for performance issues? Because splitting this up won't change the results.

Anyway, you can do this like:

```
SELECT TOP (20) rn_Attribs.ImageID AS ItemID 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM Attribs
      WHERE Attribs.attribID = '123' AND Attribs.attribID = '456') rn_Attribs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON rn_Attribs.ImageID = Items.ImageID 
WHERE(attribID IN ('a','b','c')) 
    AND (deleted NOT IN (1,2)) 
GROUP BY rn_Attribs.ImageID 
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT attribID) DESC
```

Comment: I have changed original post (please refer comments above) and tried your Query but I'm not getting any results.

Comment: Acutally, my bad...   (attribID = 'a') AND (attribID = 'b') doesn't not work

Comment: You confuse me now. What is your goal? (attribID = 'a') AND (attribID = 'b') can never get any result. And btw, why you want to split this up anyway?

Comment: Sorry, This query should be used instead of attribID ='a' and attribID = 'b'. I'm still working on it.....       SELECT ImageID, count(attribs.attribID) OVER (partition BY imageID) AS Numattribs FROM attribs WHERE attribs.attribID IN ('a','b')) a LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON a.ImageID = Items.ImageID WHERE numattribs = 2